# mongodb connection using async/await - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, mongodb-atlas

I usually use the `.then()` for MongoDB connection, because that's how I learned how to do it in the old days based on the docs.

**Is this the correct way to do it using `async await`?**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

//DB Connection
getConnection = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(
      'mongodb+srv://XXXX:XXXX@porellasmap-cluster-tgcab.mongodb.net/porellasmap',
      { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true }
    );
    console.log('Connection to DB Successful');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Connection to DB Failed');
  }
};

getConnection();

//More code
```

> FYI: The connection works

Comment: The way you did it is absolutely correct.

Comment: You did the it correctly.

Comment: use `.then()` for success and `.error()` in order to find out the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did it absolutely correct, see below official mongoose docs:

[image]

For more details :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: awesome thanks!! do you know if doing async await has any downside than using the .then()?

Comment: I don't think if there is any downside.  You should watch this: https://youtu.be/ho5PnBOoacw also there are couples of good blog you can read to find more details on Promises using then or using async-await on a promise.